# Double Tap and Drag listeners on the same view?

Tags: android, drag, gesture, ontouchlistener, double-click

I am attempting to intercept drag events as well as double tap events on the same view whereby I can drag the view to a drop location or open a dialog box if the user double taps the same view. The problem is when using a SimpleOnGestureListener to intercept the  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN event, after setting View.DragShadowBuilder(view), onDoubleTap is never called. Any ideas on how to allow a view to be dragged as well as double tapped? I was thinking a possibility would be to cancel the view.startDrag somehow on the MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL or onSingleTapUp method of the SimpleOnGestureListener but so far I haven't figured out a way to cancel the drag, if that would work at all. Thanks.

In adapter getView:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
       // AlbumHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }


    final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),new GestureListener(textview,storyItem));
                textview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                           action = event.getActionMasked();
                           return gdt.onTouchEvent(event);

                    }
                });
```

Outside Adapter in Activity:

```
  private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

         @Override
          public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent)   {

             if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    DragShadowBuilder   shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                  return true;


                  } 

              return true;
          }


          @Override
             public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e){
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "double tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                showDialog();

                return true ;

          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem before and what i did is i moved the drag&drop operation in a [onLongPress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) event of the GestureDetector.

so you can use onLongPress instead

```
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent)   {             

    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    DragShadowBuilder   shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);                        

}
```

Hope this will help you.